# use one measure value in another measure as a filter in power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am finding a measure (Max_date) from a date column (Crawl_date). I would like to use the value of that measures in another measure as a filter.-- "

Max_date = MAX('418k'[Crawl_date]).

The above "Max_date" I am using in another measure then is throwing an error message.

ex - sales/day = CALCULATE(SUM('418k'[Sales_count]),'418k'[Crawl_date] = [Max_date])

error message - a placeholder has been used in a true/false expression that is used as a table filter expression.

If am using it directly then there is no error
ex - sales/day = CALCULATE(SUM('418k'[Sales_count]),'418k'[Crawl_date] = MAX('418k'[Crawl_date]))

But I would like to use the [Max_date] ( variable ) in the filter instead of MAX('418k'[Crawl_date]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have sort of answered your own question - just use a variable to store your measure value:

```
ex - sales/day = 
VAR _max = [Max_date]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM( '418k'[Sales_count] ),
        '418k'[Crawl_date] = _max
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use variables for that:

```
ex - sales/day =
VAR _max_date = [Max_date]
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( '418k'[Sales_count] ), '418k'[Crawl_date] = _max_date )
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-variables